# Email going through even though workflow is disabled

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

We have workflow that send the email to Manager once the item is raised in the list. The problem is that when someone submits the item it send two emails to manager both are with different info in the Email Body. My believe is that there was a workflow created before and was deleted without deleting its association and now whenever we submit the form that gets called as well and sends the email. Is there a way to find out any orphaned workflow that were deleted before but still get executed in the background somehow?

Thanks,
Syed

Answer (score 2):

Try Using Following steps

1. Go to corresponding List's Setting and in list settings page click on "Workflow Settings" in Workflow settings page click on "Remove, Block, or Restore a Workflow".
2. Remove all previously running workflow instance.
3. Try to republish the the workflow with modified triggering condition from SharePoint designer.

If still you don't see your changes getting reflected to site, Try publishing the same workflow with some other person's login ( I don't know the root cause for this but it worked for me several times. I guess this is how SharePoint Behaves).

Hope this solves your Problem.

Comment: That's the thing I can't see the workflow in the Remove, Block or Restore. I have even deleted all the work flows published the whole thing again and yet the email comes. I will try the 3rd point and see if I get anywhere with. I will post the solution here once I have it.